# IllegalArgumentException in FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an app in playstore, I'm getting some crash reports and most of the crash report contains `IllegalArgumentException` exception and this exception is not pointing any of the line in my code. I could not replicate this issue. Can anyone help me out with this.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1102)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1290)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack (BackStackRecord.java:1038)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState (FragmentManager.java:1737)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManager.java:605)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed (FragmentActivity.java:179)
at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp (Activity.java:2755)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch (KeyEvent.java:2712)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent (Activity.java:3056)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatActivity.java:543)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:315)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent (DecorView.java:319)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4378)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:4349)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3893)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3946)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3920)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3893)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3946)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3920)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3893)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3946)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4072)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4233)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run (InputMethodManager.java:2430)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback (InputMethodManager.java:1994)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent (InputMethodManager.java:1985)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished (InputMethodManager.java:2407)
at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished (InputEventSender.java:141)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6290)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
```